# Django REST Framework: updating instance with unique fileds

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a model that has a unique field.

**models.py**

```
class A(models.Model):
    phonenumber = models.CharField(max_length=17,unique=True)
```

**serializers.py**

```
class ASerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = A
        fields = "__all__"

    def create(self, validated_data):
        return A.objects.create(**validated_data)

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        instance.phonenumber = validated_data.get('phonenumber', 
                                              instance.phonenumber)
        instance.save()
        return instance
```

When updating an instance of model A, if `phonenumber` is the same as before the validation error comes up : **`this field already exists in database`**.
How can I exclude the instance from validation. I already tried:

```
extra_kwargs = {
    'phonenumber' : {'validators': []},
}
```

Comment: It should be `extra_kwargs`, not `extera_kwargs`! Is this typo only here in the question or also in your code?

Comment: @cezar nope just here. I found some solution but don't know this is the rightway.instance.save(update_fields=['phonenumber'])

Comment: Did you tried `instance.phonenumber = validated_data.get('phonenumber')`  instead of `instance.phonenumber = validated_data.get('phonenumber', 
                                              instance.phonenumber)`

Comment: @VikasDamodar That's not good! If no input is given, then `phonenumber` will have the value `None`. As it is required field (implicit `null=False`) an error will be thrown. His way is ok, if no input is given, then `phonenumber` will keep the old value.

Comment: @taghiss Please post your solution as an answer. It can help other people too.